# How to add animation of div which is in append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add animation in my tittle div. here is my html code.

```
<div class="particles" id="tittle">
  <!-- Show tittle from firestore using js -->
</div>
```

css code is as follows :

```
.particles{
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  
}

.js-particles{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  animation:lightSpeedInLeft
 2s;
  transition:5s;
}

.particles{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Finally here is my java-script code that I tried:

```
// Show tittle from firestore
$("#tittle").append('<span class="js-particles"><p>'+ doc.data().tittle +'</p></span>');
```

The tittle is not animated. so, no animation is showed. How can I do this? Please help!!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Can you show the animation you're using or provide a full snippet?

Comment: Are you trying to get the p tags text to animate in from the left to the 0% y axis location of its parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the animation to start off the page and then come on to the page to a 0% position, yes?

You can use `@keyframes` to achieve this effect.

In the example below we create the `span` tag and then a `p` tag and append them to the parent element. The class, `js-particle`, is added to the span tag using `addClass()`.

Once the document loads it runs the jQuery adding the elements and class. The `@keyframes` event then runs in the specified animation-duration defined within `js-particles` where name = `from-left`. We define the `@keyframe` event using that name, then we use `translateX` to move the element on the x axis `from` a negative position in the keyframe and animate it starting at `-100%`, off the page, `to` => `0%` of the x axis position using `translateX`.

@keyframe events can animate just about any valid css function, like position, opacity, size, etc...

NOTE: I also added a `width:100%` to the parent elements css as well.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  let span = $("<span></span>");
  $("#tittle").append(span);
  let p = $("<p></p>");
  p.text("An Animated Title");// you can use the dynamic data here => + doc.data().tittle +
  span.append(p);
  span.addClass("js-particles");
})
```

```css
.particles{
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  
}

.js-particles{
  position: absolute;
  animation: linear;
  animation-name: from-left;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: from-left;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes from-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="particles" id="tittle">
  <!-- Show tittle from firestore using js -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery function called [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do that. Remove your `js-particles` CSS and do the following:

```js
const title = "Animated Title";

$("#tittle").append('<span class="js-particles"><p>' + title + '</p></span>');

$('.js-particles').animate({ 'font-size': '1.5em' }, 5000, function () {
    console.log("Animation Done")
});
```

```css
.particles{
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="particles" id="tittle">
    <!-- Show tittle from firestore using js -->
</div>
```